# division by repeated subtraction in python - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: python

```
quur = int(input('ENTER NUMBER : '))
quub = int(input('ENTER NUMBER : '))

def quureC (quur) : 

    while quur > 0 :

        quur - quub

print(" The quotient of 10 is ", (quureC (quur))
```

Answer (score 2):

So python has this cool operator "% Modulus"  that divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
quur = 10
quub = 3
print(quur % quub)

>>> 1
```

However, your code is working but it is getting stuck in an infinite loop because you are not reassigning quur.

Try this:

```
while quur > 0 :

    quur = quur - quub
```

I think this works too:

```
while quur > 0 :

    quur -= quub
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
#Gets the inputs from user
quur = int(input('ENTER NUMBER : '))
quub = int(input('ENTER NUMBER : '))



#define a method to do our division by subtraction
def quureC (quur) : 

    #Sets a variable to 0
    count = 0

    # while variable quur is less than or equal to 0 repeat
    while quur >= 0 :

        #quur is equal to quur minus quub
        quur = quur - quub
        #add one to count
        count = count + 1

    #once our while loop condition is met, return the current value of count
    return count

#quotient is assigned whatever is returned from our method quurec
quotient = quureC (quur)

#print the result
print(" the while loop repeated and the quotient is " + quotient)
```

This should work but I don't think it will return the exact result you are looking for.

Take a look at while loops: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @AndrewEarls. I what would come after the while quur > 0 : quur -= quub ? return quur ?

Comment: @AndrewEarls why you define `count` outside the function?

Comment: @Copperfield, Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't modifying the value of quur.  You want to do this instead:

```
while quur > 0:
    quur = quur - quub
```

Comment: File "", line 13
    print(" The quotient of 10 is ", (quureC (quur))
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax : This is what i got

Comment: I see three opening parentheses but only two closing parentheses on that line.

Comment: ENTER NUMBER : ENTER NUMBER : (' The quotient of 10 is ', None)- This is the error I got when I ran it

Comment: You aren't returning any value from `quureC`, therefore it returns `None` by default.

Comment: Ok. So should I have return quureC(quur) after the operation within the while block?

Comment: No, you want `return quur`.

Comment: Ok. I did that but what I want is for it to return how many times it had to subtract quub from quur. THe program is  division by subtraction

Comment: OK then, add a new variable at the top of your function and set it to zero.  Then, in your `while` loop, add one to this variable.  Return this variable at the end of the function, instead of returning quur.

Comment: quuNEW = 0,

def quureC (quur) : 
    
    while quur >= quub :
        
        quur = quur - quub,
        
        quuNEW + 1,
        
        return quuNEW- It return 0

Comment: Edit your original question to include the new behavior.  It's too hard to format lots of code in comments.

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow so I am still getting use to it.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 thing wrong with your code: first you don't modify the value of `quur` and therefore you get stuck in a infinite loop, and second the algorithm is wrong, the correct one is subtracting the denominator from the numerator while this is greater than the denominator, whatever remains is the, well, remainder and how many times you do it is the result you are searching for

```
def division(numerator,denominator):
    if denominator == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    fraction  = 0
    remainder = numerator
    while remainder >= denominator:
          remainder = remainder - denominator
          fraction  = fraction + 1
    return (fraction, remainder)
```

at the end you get number such that `numerator == denominator*fraction + remainder` were `0 <= remainder < denominator` and `fraction >= 0`

python already have this implemented as `//` operator, to get the remainder use the modulo operator `%` and to get both at the same time use `divmod`. The function above is equivalent to the build-in `divmod` of python for the most part, but the actual implementation may be different

other thing with your function is that you treat `quub` as a global variable, while that is not bad per se, it limit the flexibility of your function.

---

or is you don't like the `remainder` variable

```
def division(numerator,denominator):
    if denominator == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    fraction  = 0
    while numerator >= denominator:
          numerator = numerator - denominator
          fraction  = fraction + 1
    return (fraction, numerator)
```

in this case the final `numerator` is the remainder of the division

Comment: Hello @Copperfield, Thank you for your assistance. I am not clear some of the lines of code. What does the fraction = 0 in the if block mean? What does the remainder -= denominator do?  WHat does the fraction += 1 do? Also How can the remainder be greater than the denominator?

Comment: `fraction=0` is not in the `if` block.

Comment: The `+=` is the operator of addition in place, work that is a shortcut to `a= a+b` so you can write it as `a+=b` the same with `-=`.

Comment: And about the remainder, I first make it equal to the numerator, then it will do the first check of `remainder >= denominator` in the while loop that the first time is equivalent to `numerator >= denominator` if that fail it leave the while loop and will return that the fraction is zero and the remainder is the same as the numerator because in that case you are dividing by a greater number.

Comment: In the second case when the numerator (which value in the remainder variable) is greater or equal that the denominator then it enter the while loop and start to count how many time the denominator is the numerator until the denominator is greater and in which case whatever is left is the remainder of the division

Comment: at the end you get number such that `numerator == denominator*fraction + remainder` were `0 <= remainder < denominator` and `fraction >= 0`

Comment: Ok, please oblige my difficulty with understanding the concept, I am new to programming. I get that you equate the numerator to the remainder, so if the numerator is greater than the denominator then by definition the remainder will be also greater. Why do that though? Why not use the numerator in the same way the mathematical logic represents it. It then returns the `fraction == 0` if it fails, meaning that numerator is not greater than or equal to the denominator. When you say the denominator is the numerator, **do you mean how many denominators make up the numerator?**

Comment: yes, I wanted to said that, I intented to write "how many time the denominator is IN the numerator" but I didn't notice the mistake...

Comment: if you mean the logic of the function, well you can do the same with the `numerator` variable instead if that is more clear for you and you will get the same result, I make the `remainder` variable in a effort to make clear which each one is at the end of the function. As the remainder by definition need to follow this rule `0 <= remainder < denominator` but at start its value is unknown so I start by guessing that is the numerator and the while loop enforce the rule in case that the initial guess is wrong by making it smaller each time until the rule is satisfied

Comment: I added a version of the function without the remainder variable, maybe that way is more clear for you, both are equivalent functions

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTED CODE in 3.7

```
def divide(a,b,i=1):
    if a>b:
        c=a-b
        return divide(c,b,i+1)
    else:
        return i
print("Quotient is:",divide(n1,n2))
```

## This code works only for positive and non-zero values of a & b.